# How to know which character at what location the mouse hovers on in a DIV

Tags: javascript, html

As we know, we can use mouse envent to get target and then get the target's position in web page.

But how to know what character my mouse hovers on?

for example, in a div there is some text "Test" and my mouse is hovering on character 's'; how can I get the target is 's' and it's position like offsetTop and offsetLeft?

there are 2 solutions NOT satisfied:

1. split text into character and every character in a standalone span. it will create huge number of spans and may cause page die (correct me if i am wrong, how to avoid page die?) ...
2. use canvas and set font as div has; use measure text to get text width; this method can roughly location where we are but it is not stable; for example, we do not know how browser wrap wrods and break them into a new line...

Comment: Only spitballing here, would it be possible to get the content of the div, loop through each character and dynamically assign a function to reveal that character when you mouse over it? It sounds pretty heavy, and it sounds like another "non-satisfactory" solution (sounds like you wanna go for something more simple).

Comment: @Martin i think it is a good idea; it seems not so heavy; i can image that, if we arrange well, it will significantly decrease the number of spans. the problem is that it may break DOM selection (when i select sth in a div, and my mouse hover on a char in the div, we need to get which are selected, then remove contents, rebuild with spans when mouse enter, rebuild selections; when mouse exit, recover contents it has); more complex thing is that if the selection is related to multiple divs ...

Answer (score 1):

Would this be good for you?

```js
$cont = $('p');
parts = $.map($cont.text().split(''), function(v){
    return $('<span/>', {text:v});
});
$cont.empty().append(parts);

$(document).ready(function() {
 $('span').on('mouseover', function() {
   console.log($(this).text() + ': ' + JSON.stringify($(this).offset()))
  })
})
```

```css
p span:hover{background:#F00}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,
sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus e Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
```

Comment: I saw it but did you try with your code? Because my works for a long text.

Comment: yes, i think your code works pretty good. however, when we have more things to do like adding css and more components, it will be stuck there for some time even it can kill the page ... it is not a performant one ... i just wonder if there is any browser api to do this ...

Comment: otherwise, we can do like the method mentioned in question comments: when hover on a target, span-ize  the only target and when we finish, recover back; but one problem is that it is hard to deal with dom selections.